# Existence and uniqueness for a path dependent SDE depending on the moving average

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $\mu: \mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ and $\sigma: \mathbb  R_+ \times \mathbb R^{d} \to \mathbb R^{d \times m}$ be Lipschitz continuous in both variables and uniformly bounded.

Consider the following path dependent SDE

$$dX_t = \mu\left(t, \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t} X_s ds \right)  dt + \sigma\left(t, \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^t X_s ds\right)  dW_t$$

with $X_0 = x_0$, and $W_t$ denoting a standard $m$-dimensional Brownian motion.

**Question:** Can we show existence and uniqueness for this SDE?

Comment: Yes. It suffices to adopt the arguments used to show the existence of the strong solution to general SDEs. More precisely, define the sequence $(X^n)_{n\ge 1}$ by $X^0_t\equiv x_0$ and $X^{n+1}_t:=x_0+\int_0^t \mu(s, \overline X^n_s)ds +  \sigma(s, \overline X^n_s)dW_s$, where $\overline X^n_t:=\int_0^t X_sds/t$. Then the existence holds on $[0,T]$ for sufficiently small $T$, by the fact that $|\overline X^n_t-\overline X^{n-1}_t|\le \sup_{0\le s\le t}|X^n_s-X^{n-1}_s|$

Comment: Ah, and then we can paste solutions together. Okay I will verify the details, thanks!

Comment: Yes. You can even use more general fix point theorem. Here the argument is to construct a Cauchy sequence for small interval, and then you can paste the solutions